# Quarter of a ring with CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to create a ring shape in css, divided into 4 quarters.
Each quarter will represent a button.

I've been playing around with the following code:

```
#quarterCircleTopLeft{
     width:100px;
     height:100px;
     border:1px solid #000;
     background: orange;
     border-radius: 90px 0 70px 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 90px 0 70px 0;
     -webkit-border-radius: 90px 0 70px 0;
}
```

Which produces this (disregard the grey lines):

[image]

Obviously, I want the border at the right bottom to be inverted. However, since this is a button I cannot use another shape to produce a cutout (as this would overlap with other buttons of the menu). I've added a red line to show approx how I would want the border to go. Sorry, my paint skills are bad :-P

How can I invert the border or in another way produce the shape I want?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd do something like:

http://dabblet.com/gist/5476973

In short, lots of border radius + a white circle on top of everything.

On my example, I'd then bind click events onto the divs using javascript, or just make them all `<a>` elements instead and add a `display:block;`.

```css
/**
* Quarter Circles
*/

.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.quarter {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.quarter:hover {
  background-color: pink;
}
.quarter1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
}
.quarter2 {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 0 100% 0 0;
}
.quarter3 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
}
.quarter4 {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
}
.cutout {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="quarter quarter1"></div>
  <div class="quarter quarter2"></div>
  <div class="quarter quarter3"></div>
  <div class="quarter quarter4"></div>
  <div class="cutout"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats very helpful thanks. I did notice that the, when moving the mouse from the center (of the cutout) to one of the quarters, it doesn't seem to react right at the border of the circle. You need to move a bit further to the center of the quarter. Additionally, this distance seems to be different for each quarter. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Hmm, I'm on Chrome 28 on OSX and it doesn't seem to have that issue. If there is a problem it's probably because the inner 'circle' is a square with rounded off corners. Perhaps your browser is acting as if it's a square still. I've added `pointer-events:none;` to the inner circle – better?

Comment: Hmm yes it is better, although now the white space also lights up the button. I think its indeed considering the shapes to be squares. I am using the latest version of chrome i think (26, it says its up to date).

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot that's why I didn't put that in to start with! 26 is the latest stable version. Without using SVG to do this (which is definitely possible) then this is as good as you'll get.

Comment: You mean use images to represent the quarters? I could do that, its not to hard. Thanks for the help with this code though, I'll try and see what works better.

Comment: Though, remember that at least in Chrome 28, this works fine. Might be worth checking other places. If you use CSS3PIE this will probably even work down to IE6.

Comment: Added code from dabblet into the answer to prevent a nice answer from getting lost due to possible link rot in future.

Answer (score 2):

### Here is an <svg> solution.

**Svg has its own <a> element svg.**
Just press the corners and you will find some amazing documentation ;)
Jokes aside The a link works on the shape so the shape gets the link.
This leaves the space empty space inside the shape that will show any thing behind it.

```html
<svg width="150px" height="150px" viewbox="-1 -1 102 102">
  <a xlink:href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG">
    <path stroke="tomato" fill="orange" d="M10 50 0 50 C 0 16 16 0 50 0 V0 20 
                                         C 31 20 20 31 20 50Z" />
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG">
    <path stroke="darkRed" fill="red" transform="translate(100, 0) rotate(90)" d="M10 50 0 50 C 0 16 16 0 50 0 V0 20 
                                         C 31 20 20 31 20 50Z" />
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG">
    <path stroke="DarkBlue" fill="blue" transform="translate(100, 100) rotate(180)" d="M10 50 0 50 C 0 16 16 0 50 0 V0 20 
                                         C 31 20 20 31 20 50Z" />
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG">
    <path stroke="darkGreen" href="#" fill="green" transform="translate(0, 100) rotate(-90)" d="M10 50 0 50 C 0 16 16 0 50 0 V0 20 
                                         C 31 20 20 31 20 50Z" />
  </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: Cudos for SVG solution. You can even apply `:hover` styles to SVG elements making this answer a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

i have been able to enhance the 1st answer and avoid getting the ring respond when mouse is on cutoff area.

http://codepen.io/a-zaki/pen/rLRyAm

```css
/**
* Quarter Circles
*/

.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.quarter {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1;
}
.quarter:hover {
  background-color: pink;
}
.quarter1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
}
.quarter2 {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 0 100% 0 0;
}
.quarter3 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
}
.quarter4 {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
}
.cutout {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="quarter quarter1"></div>
  <div class="quarter quarter2"></div>
  <div class="quarter quarter3"></div>
  <div class="quarter quarter4"></div>
  <div class="cutout"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Safari this should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
  div {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: solid;
    border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
    border-width: 30px 30px 0;
    border-right: hidden;
  }
</style>
<title>Quatre Circle Outline</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```